# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appdirs' when installing pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I'm trying to install pyomo with Anaconda and keep getting the following error. I manually installed appdirs (tried both pip and conda versions) but for no good result.

Codes used:
I create conda environment;

```
conda create --n pyomo python
```

Install pyomo;

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyomo
conda install -c conda-forge pyomo.extras
```

I had to install pyutilib manually because pyomo didn't recognize this dependency automatically.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyutilib
```

Finally the pip version of appdirs

```
pip install appdirs
```

Module versions:

- Pyomo version - 5.6.6
- Appdirs version - 1.4.3

Error:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo-5.6.7a0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\pyomo\core\base\config.py in <module>
----> 1 import appdirs
      2 import os
      3 import json
      4 try:
      5     import yaml

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appdirs'
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed on your machine? Sounds like appdirs isn't installed on the version of Python you're using to run Pyomo. Could you provide more information on how you are running Python and the commands you're using to install modules?

Comment: Hi Bethany, I only have the anaconda version of python. I have multiple environments but as far as I know, having multiple versions of python in different anaconda environments should not contradict each other.

As for the commands, I add them to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you somehow ended up with conflicting or duplicate versions of Pyomo, Pyutilib, and appdirs so I would recommend redoing the installation from scratch with the following steps:

1) Uninstall Pyomo, Pyutilib, and Appdirs with the line `conda uninstall pyomo pyutilib appdirs`

2) Run the line `conda list` and make sure pyomo, pyutilib, and appdirs do not appear in your list of installed packages

3) Run the line `conda install -c conda-forge pyomo`. This should install Pyomo along with compatible versions of pyutilib and appdirs. If you run `conda list` you should see these three packages installed from the `conda-forge` channel.